# spring mongoTemplate bulk find

Tags: spring, mongotemplate

I've got an employee collection that looks like:

```
{
_id
company_id
job_type
name
age
created_at
...
}
```

I've for a list of `company_ids` and for each of them I want to get the latest 3 employees for `job_type="part_time"` and the latest 3 for `job_type="intern"` (according to the `created_at` field)

How can I do such a thing using one call?
An answer with `mongoTemplate.bulkOps` will also be valid.

Comment: On which criteria you want to sort your employees to get the 3 latest?

Comment: @charlycou `created_at` just updated, thanks for the question

Comment: Tell me if my solution suits your need. You can replace `_id` by `created_at` if the date of creation of the document doesn't correpond to the `created_at` field.

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest you can use the auto created _id field it has a date embedded in it. Assuming the name of your collection is `employee` you can use the following aggregation:

```
db.employee.aggregate([
{
    $facet: {
        "part_time": [
            {
                $match: {
                    "job_type": "part_time"
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    "company_id": "id_from_your_list"
                }
            },
            { $sort: { "_id": 1 } },
            {
                $limit: 3
            }
        ],
        "intern": [
            {
                $match: {
                    "job_type": "intern"
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    "company_id": "id_from_your_list"
                }
            },
            { $sort: { "_id": 1 } },
            {
                $limit: 3
            }
        ]
    }
}])
```

I assume that you are using spring data mongodb you can execute this aggregation operation using `MongoTemplate` helper.

```
FacetOperation facetOperation = facet().and(match(Criteria.where("job_type").is("part_time")),match(Criteria.where("company_id").is("company_id_from_your_list")),
sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id"),
limit(3)).as("part_time")
.and(match(Criteria.where("job_type").is("intern")),match(Criteria.where("company_id").is("company_id_from_your_list")),
sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id"),
limit(3)).as("intern");
mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(facetOperation), "employee", Document.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
```